# Is there a way to make a copy of a java project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project in eclipse workspace.  I would like to make another program from this project.  Is there a way to make a copy of the project?
Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only an exact copy, then:

1. Just go to your workspace direcrtory, make copy of your project folder and rename it.
2. Go back to Eclipse, refresh your project explorer.

Answer (score 2):

you can select the project and use copy paste of the Edit menu to create 
a clone of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Export it using File -> Export, it will correctly export all the required files and settings.